# Unconfirmed/blockchain reset issue

Tags: transactions, blockchain, unconfirmed-transactions

Hey guys been looking through the forums and I'm still not quite sure how to speed things up or fix it. (Not very good with this kind of stuff)

Here's my wallet address - 1GZK3NYHCAScGRb4awAkXGVXszstwCVEEh

Initial problem:

Both transactions say they have been seen by 50+ peers 
But hadn't been confirmed for 24hrs

I used the standard multi bit classic fee 0.0001
Which has never slowed me down in past.

- i figured it was too low of a fee. Changed my settings for next time

New problem:

I did a 'reset blockchain and transaction' (did it twice) on multibit classic - seems to be no way to change date etc. in an attempt to get my coins back and start again

Now the amount of 1 of the 2 transactions is showing in my balance (but isn't spendable) and the other seems to have made no change (still sending to the same address, just the peers have reset)

I've looked on blockchain.info and nothing seems to have changed at all.

Do I need to just be patient?

I just don't really understand what's happening or what I'm looking at.

If someone could help me fix it or explain what's going on that would be appreciated

I'm confident once I get my coins back and send with a higher fee it'll all be fine. Just can't seem to get them a back

Cheers!

Ps. Sorry I'm a noob and stressing

Answer (score 1):

Hey everyone fixed my own problem with viabtc

I recommend using them if you have been waiting. Both transactions started confirming within the hour!

My fee was between 28 - 50 sat/b

So if you have given a fee that's low (no lower than 0.0001 Btc) then go with these guys